Alternative to bare except in Python?
Documentation on exception handling tends to focus on using specific exception types – which is good advice in general.
However there are times I want to run some Python code which under no circumstances throws an exception that isn't handled and stops the program from running:
For example, a graphical application might run a user-defined script. I don't know what errors that script could trigger, so it's not useful to check for specific errors:
try:
    run_script_file(filepath)
except:
    import traceback
    print("Script:", filepath, "failed with error!")
    traceback.print_exc()

This works, but code checking tools warn that bare except should not be used. While I could suppress the warnings in each case, I was considering using except BaseException: to quiet the warnings.

Is a bare except: guaranteed to be the equivalent of except BaseException: or are there subtle differences where a bare except might catch exceptions a BaseException wouldn't?

That script could do all sorts of things that no except statement could possibly handle. Arbitrary memory corruption, os._exit(0), messing with the file system...

@user2357112 yes, it must be trusted not to malicious operations, however I don't want an exception to cause the graphical application to cease functioning. This could be a trusted plugin for instance - that happens to have a mistake in its code.

But a malfunctioning plugin is quite likely to corrupt your application's data structures. Perhaps not on the level of what an outright malicious plugin would do, but still at the point where it would probably be better to abort execution rather than risk things getting even worse.

@user2357112 it depends a lot on the use-case, one example is a callback from a plugin that returns a documentation-URL - logically this is a read-only operation although it's possible the plugin uses it's own internal cache. Whatever the case - if there is an error I don't want the application to exist or crash. It can report there was an error looking up the URL and continue.

From the documentation:

In Python, all exceptions must be instances of a class that derives from BaseException.

Also noted in PEP8 (emphasis mine):

A bare except: clause will catch SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt exceptions, making it harder to interrupt a program with Control-C, and can disguise other problems. If you want to catch all exceptions that signal program errors, use except Exception: (bare except is equivalent to except BaseException:).

So, yes, they're equivalent.

Of course, the script could do something like import builtins; builtins.BaseException = 5, which would mess with an except BaseException. It could also do all sorts of worse things.

@user2357112 That's true, but if you're concerned about situations like this then Python is not the language for you.

My question doesn't relate to malicious scripts - which can do all sorts of bad things if they want, the purpose of handing the exception in this case isn't to guard against bad actors, just prevent errors in the code from propagating where they shouldn't.
